# How do I get the address of the entity deploying a contract?

Tags: solidity, web3js

I am deploying a contract factory via code (Web3js.). In the contract factory, I wish to determine my address automatically. How do I do this?

Comment: Which IDE are you using?

Comment: Remix and Webstorm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally you can get accounts by the command

```
web3.eth.getAccounts();
```

And if you want to get the first account you can use the following command.

```
web3.eth.getAccounts().then(e => let account1=e[0]; 
console.log(account1));
```

Since you are using web3.js, I am assuming you are using truffle and ganache. So generally first account is default deployment address in the truffle.

**Edit**:

```
//SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity ^0.8.10;


contract getAddress {

    address public deployer; //Solidity compiler automatically generates getter function for public variables.

    constructor()    {
        deployer = msg.sender; //msg.sender gives the address of the current user. Since we are declaring in the constructor it is akin to the owner of the contract and also deployer.
    }


    function getContractAddress() public view returns(address) {
        return address(this); //address(this) gives the address of the contract.
    } 
}
```

Comment: I want to do this right in the Solidity code, though.

Comment: You mentioned web3js. So I answered in web3.js. Anyways I am gonna add solidity script to get deployer address and the address of a contract.